# Pandas: apply different functions to different columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

When using `df.mean()` I get a result where the mean for each column is given. Now let's say I want the mean of the first column, and the sum of the second. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to have to disassemble and reassemble the `DataFrame`.

My initial idea was to do something along the lines of `pandas.groupby.agg()` like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,2)), columns=['A','B'])
df.apply({'A':np.mean, 'B':np.sum}, axis=0)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-265d3e797682>", line 1, in <module>
    df.apply({'A':np.mean, 'B':np.sum}, axis=0)

  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3471, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)

  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3560, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)

TypeError: ("'dict' object is not callable", u'occurred at index A')
```

But clearly this doesn't work. It seems like passing a dict would be an intuitive way of doing this, but is there another way (again without disassembling and reassembling the `DataFrame`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can use the `agg` method with a dictionary as the argument. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': [3, 4, 5]})

df =
A   B
0   0   3
1   1   4
2   2   5

df.agg({'A': 'mean', 'B': sum})

A     1.0
B    12.0
dtype: float64
```

To add, it seems the example provided in the question also works now (as of version 1.5.3).

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,2)), columns=['A','B'])
df.apply({'A':np.mean, 'B':np.sum}, axis=0)

A    0.495771
B    5.939556
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 17):

You can try a closure:

```
def multi_func(functions):
    def f(col):
        return functions[col.name](col)
    return f

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
result = df.apply(multi_func({'A': np.mean, 'B': np.sum}))
```

Comment: This is pretty nice actually. My workaround was inserting a column of ones into the dataframe, doing groupby on that column then passing a dict to the aggregate method.

Comment: Thank you! I notice that this fails if there are more columns in the DataFrame than keys in the function dict. @bill-letson have you seen that too?

Comment: A full implementation should include a try KeyError clause which returns an identity function: lambda x : x

Comment: @phil_20686 You can do that by replacing `functions[col.name](col)` with `functions.get(col.name, lambda x: x)(col)`

Comment: If you want to do this in a one liner, the following solution worked for me: `df.apply(lambda x: functions.get(x.name, lambda x: x)(x))`

Answer (score 2):

Just faced this situation myself and came up with the following:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four'], ['five', 'six']], 
   ...:                   columns=['A', 'B'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
       A     B
0    one   two
1  three  four
2   five   six

In [4]: converters = {'A': lambda x: x[:1], 'B': lambda x: x.replace('o', '')}

In [5]: new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({col: series.apply(converters[col]) 
   ...:                               if col in converters else series
   ...:                               for col, series in df.iteritems()})

In [6]: new
Out[6]: 
   A    B
0  o   tw
1  t  fur
2  f  six
```